# How to insert images with graphicx?

Tags: graphics

I'm trying to insert an image to my file, but I can't figure out how to do it. I've added

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

to my preamble and when I drag and drop an image to my file (I'm working with TeXStudio), the following code appears:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{"My Pretty Image"}
\end{figure}
```

However, this doesn't want to work.

What did I do wrong and how can I solve this?

Comment: The last parameter to `\includegraphcs` needs to be the file name.

Comment: @PeterGrill: The filename is `Oefening 1a_tabel AB.png`. Using that with or without the extention doesn't work...

Comment: Don't use spaces in filenames. And remove the quotes.

Comment: Remove the `"` around the filename

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Great, that solved my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Ulrike Fischer to answer this question in the comments: "Don't use spaces in filenames. And remove the quotes."

The correct code is therefore:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{MyPrettyImage}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
A complete answer for just reference.
\bigskip % Add an empty line
%These are optional parameters to finetune the placement of tables and figures, with the following meaning:
%
%h, here
%t, top
%b, bottom
%p, page of float
%e.g. \begin{figure}[!htb]
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=90mm]{imagename.png}
\caption{This is the caption}
\label{overflow}
\end{figure}
```